# Using Netbeans Server

Tags: java, servlets

Im trying to use Netbeans to run a web server. The class compiles fine but doesn't do much, only compiles. Now when I move to the terminal and try to run it like so:

```
java -jar webserver.jar garage.html 82 ASCII
```

I get a Port Occupied Error. Now I'm trying to change the port number to get this to run but I don't know how. I read on SO that it can be done via Netbeans but where? Also I know it can be done by accessing the server.xml file on Netbeans but where do I find this?

Comment: netbeans is just an IDE, it cannot run web servers. are you trying to run a web service (not the same as web server)?

Comment: well the server is suppose to be accessed locally - when i compile at the terminal I get the error above therefore I'm pretty sure it's a web server not a service.